# Brightness bug after upgrading Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, brightness

I had Ubuntu 12.10 on my PC, and I did the upgrade to Ubuntu 13.10. But now I have a problem with brightness control, it is always on maximum level and I can't set it neither with <kbd>fn</kbd> nor with brightness control in the system settings nor with `xbacklight` or other method.

I had tried changing `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT value`, but nothing happens.

How can I fix this problem?

I have ubuntu 13.10 64bit, kernel 3.11.0-13, on a Toshiba Portege R930, Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-3520M CPU @ 2.90GHz × 4; Graphic: Intel® Ivybridge Mobile

Comment: you may try this command: sudo su -c "echo 110 >/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness", of course you may change 110 to any arbitrary value

Answer (score 1):

I added `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=vendor"` into `/etc/defaults/grub`, updated grub and restarted PC.

Comment: This also fixes the brightness bug that is present in 12.04 with other hardware, this repaired the brightness issue on my Precise machine.